# Actions not being passed to redux in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I followed the instructions set out in https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/v3/REDUX_FLUX.md#step-1 to a tee in version beta.24 and when I navigate via Action.push, pop, replace, etc there is no corresponding action that is passed through to my reducer.

i print at the top of my reducer and can capture events I pass through dispatch manually. Are there common issues that I could run into?

Code

**Reducer**

```
import { ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const initialState = {
    scene: {},
};

export default function SceneReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionConst.FOCUS:
            return { ...state, scene: action.scene };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Combined Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SceneReducer from './SceneReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    routing: SceneReducer,
    // other reducer here...
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**App**

```
import RootReducer from './RootReducer';

import loginRouter from './LoginRouter';
const ReduxRouter = connect()(Router);

const store = compose(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))(createStore)(RootReducer);

const navigator = Actions.create(
    <Modal hideNavBar>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
            <Scene key='login1' component{Log1} />
            <Scene key='login2' component{Log2} />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key="modalRoot"><Scene key="modal" component={Comp} /></Scene>
    </Modal>,
);

export default class AppRouter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ReduxRouter scenes={navigator} />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Try replace your `ReduxRouter` with this:

```
import { Router, Reducer } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ReduxRouter = connect()(({ dispatch, children, ...props }) => (
  <Router
    {...props}
    createReducer={params => (state, action) => {
      dispatch(action);
      return Reducer(params)(state, action);
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </Router>
));
```

Also, for the reducer, the action's route key is `routeName` rather than `scene` (maybe your version differs so look out for both):

[image]

I'm using `"react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.27"`.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm with 4.0.0-beta.27 and redux 3.7.2

Comment: @Syd will this change route from the state?

Comment: @AntoAntony your routing is stored in redux, that's the point here.

Comment: @Syd that's right. But the issue is react-native-router-flux is not taking the router state from store. for example time series debugging is not working. do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are some of the modifications that you need to do in your code.

You need to implement and use [**reducer**](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/Reducer.js) object from `react-native-router-flux`, which defines and handles the actions appropriately.

Then bind it to your **SceneReducers.js** as

```
import {Reducer, ActionConst, Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'

const defaultReducer = Reducer();

export default (state, action) => {
console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
      case ActionConst.FOCUS:
          return defaultReducer(state, action);

      default:
        return defaultReducer(state, action);
  }
}
```

> It is important to load reducers **AFTER** `actions.create`, so don't use import here.

This is because the `initial state` of the reducer' must be available at **compile time** and `Router` is created **runtime**.

Therefore in your **App** use

```
// create actions
// connect your router to the state here
const ReduxRouter = connect((state) => ({ state: state.routing }))(Router);
const RootReducer = require('./RootReducer').default;

// define the store
const store = compose(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))(createStore)(RootReducer);
```

Have a look at this [thread](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2115#issuecomment-360711190) to `follow-up`.You might run into issues due to non-deep linking of the external states, therefore you can check it on version until `4.0.0-beta.23` as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2115#issuecomment-360711190) comment.

*Hope it helps*